# Submitting radio button values without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm currently having radio buttons to choose which payment the user want on the website, they can choose between (invoice, card, part payment(?)).

I'm using scripting to submit the radio buttons so no button is needed, however the page reloads every time they choose a different payment option, which is bad for the customer since they have to scroll down again to input the values of the form (phone number etc.) that appear when the radio button is selected.

So after a few complaints I've been trying to fix this issue to make the form appear without the page getting refreshed.

Is it possible to make a few changes in the scripting to make this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the scripting i use:

```
function autoSubmit(){
    var formObject = document.forms['choice_form'];
    formObject.submit();
}
```

Here's the PHP: //I use the post values to show the form where you enter phone number and email

```
<?php 
 $value = '';
  if(isset($_POST['choice'])) {
   $value = $_POST['choice'];
  }
?>
```

Here's the "radio" form:

```
<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" method="post">
   <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if ($value == 'faktura') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> onChange="autoSubmit();" value="faktura"> Faktura
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if ($value == 'kort-direkt') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> onChange="autoSubmit();" value="kort-direkt"> Kort / Direktbetalning
      </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" <?php if ($value == 'delbet') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> onChange="autoSubmit();" value="delbet"> Delbetalning
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Add `return false;` to your `autoSubmit()` function.

Comment: Depending on how `autoSubmit()` is called/bound, you can try returning `false` from it.

Comment: Or you can use `AJAX`.

Comment: AJAX is your answer, but why you are submitting this radio buttons before everything else?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I've tried this and the page is still refreshing.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've tried some examples but I'm rather new to it so I've not got it to work.

Comment: @Volvox I'm submitting the radio buttons to show the other forms so to speak.

Comment: Try `onChange="autoSubmit(); return false;"` in your radio button markup.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I still get a page refresh.

Comment: Okay but why do you wanna submit the form? `formObject.submit()` always submits the form and initiate a page refresh. If you just want to display different forms based on the radio button you can do it without using a submit.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I don't have to submit the form, as solymosi says i'm trying to work on a script that checks the value of the radio buttons and displays the corresponding div instead.

Comment: Okay then don't execute `formObject.submit();` in `autoSubmit()` but set the `display` of your div to `block`. You don't need to submit the form for this  at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every time a payment option is selected a different form needs to appear underneath the radio buttons, you could render all forms in hidden state in individual `<div>`s, and then display the corresponding `<div>` every time an option is selected.

If you need to do something more complex than that, you will probably need to use AJAX.

Comment: True, but won't the form still need to be submitted to get a value from the radio button?

Comment: If you only use the radio buttons to show/hide different form parts then you don't need to submit the value back to the server in order to determine which form part to display. At the end of the form there is a submit button, right? That's when the form will finally be submitted, along with the specific payment method data.

Comment: There is a submit button at the end yes to insert the data into the database. I will give it a shot with the divs to see if i can make it work.